# Trying to decode arrays with Argo

Tags: arrays, json, swift, generics

I am trying to decode data from JSON into a very generic struct using Argo (https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo):

```
struct ValueBox<T: Decodable where T == T.DecodedType> {
    let value: T
}

extension ValueBox: Decodable {
    static func decode(json: JSON) -> Decoded<ValueBox> {
        let r = curry(ValueBox.init)
            <^> json <| "value"
        return r
    }
}


extension Array: Decodable {
    public typealias DecodedType = Array<Element>
}

extension Array {
    public static func decode(json: JSON) -> Decoded<Array<Element>> {
        return Decoded<Array>.customError("not implemented")
    }
}
```

This compiles. I know it would not be able to decode ValueBox in case of T being an array. But that is a second problem.

If I now try to use Argo for decoding:

```
func testExample() {
    let jsonDict_Int: [String : AnyObject] = [
        "value" : 5
    ]

    let jsonDict_IntArray: [String : AnyObject] = [
        "value" : [5]
    ]

    let intBox: Decoded<ValueBox<Int>> = decode(jsonDict_Int)
    let intArrayBox: Decoded<ValueBox<Array<Int>>> = decode(jsonDict_IntArray)
}
```

I get a compiler error that "`Array<Int>` does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'". But why? I provided the extension to make it conform, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

For the second example, I think you must use `<^> json <|| "value"` instead of `<^> json <| "value"`

> When you use an Array of value you must use the operator <||

[a great link to the detailed Argo's documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo/blob/master/Documentation/Basic-Usage.md)

Comment: As I said, this is problem number 2. But it is difficult because <|| would decode to [T] and T already is the array.

Comment: Yes but you can't do that.You must do something special for an Array. Because when you do ValueBox<Array<Int>> he try to put T as Array<Int> and the compiler want [T] as Array<Int>.